# Rails: what is the url to an image hosted in assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, url, routes

I have an image hosted on my rails server in the assets folder, I'd like to access this image through an url rather than using the path so that I can display it in my react component.

How can I find the url for said image so that when I go to the url the image will be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use image_tag. If you have "image.png" in your assets, you can use

```
<%= image_tag "image.png" %>
```

and it will result in a URL like this

```
/assets/image-bb14d53a12ca1aa006defb5c0f0923aa3c946f7e2dfd534846b3a1d3b8aac72e.png
```

When using image_tag, Rails creates a random token for image authentication. You can't just use `<img src="/assets/image.png` because there is no token.

Comment: The thing is I'm using react with my rails app and I want to display an image hosted on my server through a react component, so I need the url as react does not recognize the image_tag syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Rails' assets pipeline creates a digest of each asset and adds that to the filename, so the name is not always the same, you can't just copy it and use it forever (you can make rails recreate all the digests and all the urls are changed for example).

I can think of few options:

1 - Disable the assets pipeline digest feature
On your environment's config file, add `config.assets.digest = false` and now the name won't have the digest at the end. Read the docs though, since the digest is there for a reason, you can disable it but it's better to decide that after reading the doc.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-digests-off

2 - Move those images to /public
If you move the images to /public, they won't be compiled by the assets pipeline.

3 - Use a gem like non-stupid-digest to select which assets should have it
https://rubygems.org/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets lets you configure some assets to prevent the assets pipeline to skip the digest generation without turning off the feature for all the assets

4 - Let the assets pipeline alone and put the urls somewhere on your html
To get the correct current path of an image, you can use the helper `image_path` (for example: `image_path('something.png')` returns `/assets/something-123...890.png`). You can then write that on your template like:

```
<script>
  imageUrl = '<%= image_url('something.png') %>';
</script>
```

And you'll have access to that imageUrl variable on your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will need to go into your **public** folder and then to **assets**.

Find the image you want and then copy it's name.

You will need to call it like: `/assets/img-name-033cce876b38fb47072fb3668a5.jpg` or `/assets/folder/` before the image name if it's in another folder and so on.